# Android, AOA2, USB Isochronous Audio Streaming

Tags: android, audio, usb, linux-device-driver, device-driver

Using `AOA v2` protocol, a android device can output its audio stream to some accessory connected over an `USB`. But is it possible for the accessory to send over its `audio stream` to android device so that the android device will act as an `USB speaker`?

I'm actually planning to write a `USB speaker` driver using `AOA` protocol, but I just got stuck here. Because I can make the device initialize in `AOA` mode, but can't get the endpoints for audio interface. So I kind of leaning towards to believe that audio input to android device isn't possible using `AOA`. Anyone has any experience with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Android OS v5, Audio to the device ( Mic use-case ) is not supported, what you can do to achieve what you're trying, is, to use BlueTooth to simulate a headset where you have bi-directional audio.

- On Linux you can use the BluZ BT stack ( quite powerful )
- On Windows you'll have to implement a BT Profile Driver